# Accurev Externals?

Tags: svn-externals, accurev

Does Accurev have a feature like SubVersions '[svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s04.html)'?  This works like a symbolic link to another area of the repository.

Example: In my subversion test automation projects I had my shared libraries defined as a 'svn:externals' within each test project.  This made it easy to work with relative paths as everything needed appeared to be a child of the top project folder. I have attempted to show this below.

```
Shared_Libraries (the real one)

Project_1
 -> Project_specific_code
 -> Shared_Libraries (external reference)

Project_2
 -> Project_specific_code
 -> Shared_Libraries (external reference)
```

Thanks

Glenn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AccuRev supports both traditional symbolic links (for the linux/unix world) as well as our own element links (elinks).  My guess is that if you're not on *nix, you could easily use element links to create references to those shared libraries at the correct folder level for what you need...

Check out our documentation on element links (elinks) for how to implement.

Regards,
~James